# How to do Normalization?

Tags: sql, database-design

Hi i am new to this concept and i need your suggestion. i have an excel spreadsheet having about 35 columns and i have to create tables out of it. i have to draw an ER diagram but i dont know which should be the main table having foreign keys of all other tables or is there going to be one main table or multiple main tables?

Comment: You need to provide a LOT more information.  This basically is not even a question...

Comment: but you didn't in the hour plus it took to get it closed?  Nothing is stopping you from asking a new question with more precision.

Answer (score 3):

[Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is a database concept - it is all about removing redundancies from your data.

There are several different normalization forms, each building on top of the previous.

First normal form - each column in a table should only hold *one* value, so things like a comma separated list is a no no.

To be honest, the subject matter can get very complex - see [this](http://www.troubleshooters.com/littstip/ltnorm.html) article on how to apply normalization to a table.